# Chat Box area in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I am trying to adjust a chatbox area in Java Swing. It appears to be at the top while I need it at the bottom of my frame.

My code:

```
package com.javavalley;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.Thread;


import java.lang.Math;

public class ChatBot extends JFrame{
    
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea chatArea;
    private JTextField chatBox;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private Border border;
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ChatBot();
    }
    
    public ChatBot(){
        frame = new JFrame("Product Bot");
        chatArea = new JTextArea(20,50);
        chatBox = new JTextField();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(chatArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        
        chatArea.setSize(540, 400);
        chatArea.setLocation(30,5);
        chatBox.setSize(540, 30);
        chatBox.setLocation(18, 18);
        chatBox.setBorder(border);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.add(chatBox);
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        bot("Hello! I am a \"Product Bot\"! that answers product related queries! Ask me by typing below. Type \"QUIT\" to end the program. \n\n");
        chatArea.append("Chats: \n");
        chatBox.setText("");
        
        chatBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                String gtext = chatBox.getText();
                chatArea.append("You: " +gtext + "\n");
                chatBox.setText("");
                if(gtext.equals("QUIT")) {
                    sleep(500);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                String category = "";
                try {
                        category = com.javavalley.ProBot.findCategory(gtext);
                        System.out.println(category);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception thrown.");
                }
                String response = respond(category);
                bot(response);
                }
            }); 
            
            
        }
        
        private void bot(String string)
        {
            chatArea.append("Bot: " + string + "\n");
        }
        
        
        private void sleep(int x) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(x);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        private String respond(String category)
        {
            String[] greetings = {"Hello, how can I help you?"};
            String[] conversationContinue = {"How can I help you with?", "What else can I help you with?"};
            String[] colorsinquiry = {"Black, Blue, Green, Red, Sierra Blue"};
            String[] priceinquiry = {"Price is EUR 279"};
            String[] productinquiry = {"Product is an Android 11 smart phone with latest features like Super AMOLED Display, 6.5 inches, Li-Ion 5000 mAh, non-removable battery, Octa-core (4x1.6 GHz Cortex-A55 & 4x1.2 GHz Cortex-A55))"};
            String[] conversationComplete = {"Goodbye", "Bye", "Nice chatting with you. Bye!"};
            
            if (category.equals("greeting")) return greetings[(int) (Math.random()*greetings.length)];
            else if (category.equals("colors-inquiry")) return colorsinquiry[(int) (Math.random()*colorsinquiry.length)];
            else if (category.equals("price-inquiry")) return priceinquiry[(int) (Math.random()*priceinquiry.length)];
            else if (category.equals("product-inquiry")) return productinquiry[(int) (Math.random()*productinquiry.length)];
            else if (category.equals("conversation-continue")) return conversationContinue[(int) (Math.random()*conversationContinue.length)];
            else if (category.equals("conversation-complete")) return conversationComplete[(int) (Math.random()*conversationComplete.length)];
            else return "Sorry";
        }
        
}
```

P.S: Added the prototype code. The thing I am trying to produce is a complete GUI with some chat history. Also I wanted to have it in a rectangular window and some UI improvements.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html#choosing  try to use layout managers

Comment: I tried to turn the code into something that would compile and run but got stuck at the `bot`. What is it, another text field? For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre]. It would also help to add a drawing or ASCII art of the intended look of the GUI.

Comment: Is the GUI supposed to appear something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueC2i.png)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Yes I would like to have it the way you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

> Yes I would like to have it the way you showed.

[image]

This is what you might see if the bottom text field is swapped for a `JLabel` (which seems more logical here) but the layout is identical.

This is the code that produced the screenshot seen above. (It is also an MRE as I hope you will post in future. I could have sorted the problem in half the time, had it not been for 'filling in the blanks' of the original code).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

class ChatBot {
    JFrame frame;
    JTextArea chatArea;
    JTextField chatBox;
    Border border;
    JScrollPane scroll;

    public ChatBot() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
        frame = new JFrame("Product Bot");
        frame.setContentPane(gui);
        chatArea = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        chatBox = new JTextField();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(chatArea,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 1);
        chatBox.setBorder(border);

        JLabel bot = new JLabel(
                "Hello! I am a \"Product Bot\"! that answers product related queries! " +
                "Ask me by typing below. Type \"QUIT\" to end the program.");
        chatArea.append("Chats: \n");
        chatBox.setText("Chat Box");

        gui.add(chatBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        gui.add(scroll);
        gui.add(bot, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChatBot();
    }
}
```

I forgot to carefully document the changes made (in code comments). If, after carefully examining the code and relevant Java Docs there is any change you do not understand, ask me in a comment & I'll explain further.

Comment: I would like to know is there a way to show images also within the JFrame along with the text?

Comment: If you want to mix text and images in Swing then go for an EditorPane. More complex than a TextArea but also more powerful.

Comment: Usually it is best to put each question on a separate thread, but the short answer is: A `JTextArea` is built for plain text. To embed images and (formatted) text in the same component, look to one that supports 'rich text', such as a `JEditorPane`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a Layout.
Here I suggest https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

Which is the default layout anyway, so you can do :

```java
public ChatBot(){
        ...
        frame.add(chatBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        ...
}
```

You can mix Layout and you should create panels that groups simple elements.

Comment: I forgot before, but feel this answer is worthy of an upvote for 3 reasons. 1) It links to the tutorial for the border layout. 2) It uses the logical rather than the 'compass' constants for placing components (particularly `LINE_START` and `LINE_END` automatically accommodate both left-to-right and right-to-left languages). 3) Mentioning that layouts can be combined. It was not necessary for this very simple layout, but there are very few GUIs I write that use only a single layout.